# Exceptional divisor of blow-up of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:X\to\mathbb{P}^n$ be a blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ along a subspace $Z:=\mathbb{P}^m\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$, $n-m\geq2$. How does the exceptional divisor of $\pi$ look like?

Comment: If you blow up a smooth subvariety in a smooth ambient $Z\subseteq X$, the restriction of $\widetilde{X}\to X$ to $Z$ can be identified with the projectivization of the normal bundle of $Z$ in $X$. Moreover you can describe its ideal sheaf on the blowup in terms of the ideal sheaf of $Z$ on $X$. You can find all this in Hartshorne's book (for example).

Comment: Yes. it will be just the projectivization of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(1)^{\oplus n-m}$.

Comment: But how to compute explicitly this projectivization?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly"?

Comment: I computed this, it is just $\mathbb{P}^{r-1}\times\mathbb{P}^m$.